# Bar number featuring this tone row by Schoenberg in the sheet music

Tags: theory, analysis, atonal, serial

Given is an image of the tone row used by Schoenberg in his *Variations for Orchestra op. 31*. This is what was given in a music theory workbook. 
[image]

I found the sheet music for the Schoenberg piece. But I'm not able to find out exactly in which bar of the piece is this tone row used. I can find the use of some of the notes of the tone row in the first two pages of the sheet music. I would appreciate if anyone could tell me in which bars does this tone row appear in.

Comment: are we doing your homework? 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variations_for_Orchestra_(Schoenberg) . But thank you anyway for the inspiration. You can also translate this site:
https://www.schoenberg.at/index.php/de/joomla-license-sp-1943310035/variationen-fuer-orchester-op-31-1926-1928

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli No, this isn't part of my homework! I am curious to understand Schoenberg's style of music, since this is totally new to me. I thought of analysing his style by looking at the sheet music myself, but was kind of lost. Hence thought of asking the question.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Neither of those links are any help here

Comment: "Variations" is a huge piece. If you are starting off analysing 12 tone music by yourself, you would probably find it much easier to start with one of Schoenberg's string quartets

Comment: As Hugli points out- we prefer people do their own research on specialized topics like this.  In this case, the entire score is available at imslp.org

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I assume OP already has the score. There seems to be no good analysis of this work available online which makes the question a good fit on SE

Comment: We don't usually track down measure numbers for sheet music excerpts. This would have been better for chat, or another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two pages show Schoenberg constructing the tone row from its component parts. He starts by exploring the tritone interval of the first two notes for the first four bars, adding the tritone G-C# (an inversion) in bar 3. Then he adds the major second interval (the second two notes). In bar 8 he starts the first five notes of the tone row (fl/harp) together with the same notes inverted and transposed (bcl/bsn/harp). Then he starts a transposed inversion of the tone row in bars 9 and 10 (bcl/bsn/cb). The first complete statement is in bars 10 to 13 (fl/harp/vln1 taken over by  bcl/bsn/vcl)